# jQuery Textarea Caret Position to End on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, textarea, caret

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you move the cursor to the last position of a textarea in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637287/how-can-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-last-position-of-a-textarea-in-javascript)

I have multiple textareas on a page and would like to set the position of the caret to the end of the text which changes per textarea (textareas do not contain similar length values).

How would I initiate this on focus to move caret from the position they select to the end?

Thanks in advance.

-B

Comment: This has largely been answered before on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637287/how-can-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-last-position-of-a-textarea-in-javascript