# New line is not working in editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is Html code:

```
<div id="messageBox" contenteditable="true" class="message"></div>
```

And this is jquery:

```
$('#messageBox').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $(this).html($(this).html() + "<br>");
        }
    }).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $('#send').trigger('click');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I want to create a new line by pressing Ctrl+Enter but it does not work.The cursor does not move.
[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQztJ/6/)

Comment: That's because there's nothing after the `<br>`. It gets inserted, but the browser doesn't display it. You can verify this by changing your `"<br>"` to `"<br>foo"`.

Comment: It's working fine for me, just tried your fiddle in both Chrome and Firefox

Comment: The cursor does not move.

Comment: Changing the whole HTML of the element is somewhat rude. You could use a Range object to [add a new-line](http://jsfiddle.net/yt8drrat/)  anywhere in the contenteditable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get this working for you as I'll provide below. I would suggest pre populating your `<div>` with a `<br />` like

```
<div id="messageBox" contenteditable="true" class="message">
    <br />
</div>
```

Although thus looks weird, it gets the browser an "anchor" to place the cursor on to start. You'll notice odd behavior if you remove this and try to "add a new line" for the first time. Also as a comments suggest, you were overlaying your html each time, which could generate a lot of overhead and undesired behavior depending on how involved your project becomes, so for this example I simply append as such `$(this).append('<br />')`

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/t420qL7p/)

```
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined'
            && typeof document.createRange != 'undefined') {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != 'undefined') {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}

$('#messageBox')
    .keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {            
            $(this).append('<br />');    
            placeCaretAtEnd($('#messageBox').get(0));
        }
    }).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#send').trigger('click');
            return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample works for me just fine. Make sure your browser supports contenteditable. Below is the list of browsers that do support it.

```
Chrome  4.0+
Safari  3.1+
Mobile Safari   5.0+
Firefox 3.5+
Opera   9.0+
Opera Mini/Mobile   N/A
Internet Explorer   5.5+
Android 3.0+
```

Also, in same cases you might need to wrap it in a container that has contenteditable="false".

The cursor is not going to move, since you're only appending the text. Check this on how to move the cursor to the end [How can you move the cursor to the last position of a textarea in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637287/how-can-you-move-the-cursor-to-the-last-position-of-a-textarea-in-javascript)

Comment: New line is created but the cursor does not move and a text will be written on the first line.

Comment: Check my updated answer showing how to move the cursor to the end of the line